# making a blender addon (in python) that has a keyboard shortcut and works in edit mode (not object mode as per example)

Tags: python, scripting, shortcut

I am trying to make a blender addon using this template (last example on page):
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html

I have successfully got my addon to work with a shortcut (I override the plus and minus keys), but when flicking to edit mode, the shortcut no longer works.

The example only shows how to make a shortcut for object mode.

How can I make a shortcut for edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

i found you can use the keymap word "Screen Editing" instead of "Object Mode"

```
object_mode_keys = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Screen Editing', space_type='EMPTY')
```